# Inconsistent https/http iframe security

Tags: iframe, ssl, localhost

I have been struggling with inconsistent development around an https site with iframes of a non-http site (which does not offer https). The main issue is in testing on my local machine (using `https://localhost/` or any domain mapped to 127.0.0.1) there is no security violation, so the problem only shows up once deployed.

I've been running into this with chrome 27 on linux.

Is there any way to enforce the security even while on localhost or if there this is something else I'm missing?